# losing the decimals when multiplying a decimal number times a hole number in R

Tags: r

I´m multiplying a whole number in R (numeric) with a decimal number (numeric) but the output is always without decimals.

i.e 0.14 * 7 = 1, instead of 0.98

How can a make this operation and get the decimals?

I expected to get the product e´with 2 decimals.

Comment: [`options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html)`(digits=2)` or some higher number

Comment: Realize that how R _renders_ a number on the console is different from what is stored in the number. For instance, see that `pi` when viewed with `options(digits=1)`; with `digits=2` then it is `3.1`; with `digits=3` then it is `3.14`; for all of them, though, `pi` is still and always 3.14159265...

Comment: Have tried to use the digits option but don´t get it working. The syntax is like this: Dataset$Score <- Dataset$Factor1*Dataset$Factor2

Comment: Literally: `options(digits=9); 0.14*7` prints `[1] 0.98` to the console. What else are you expecting?

Comment: @jay.sf Multiplication of factors gives `NA` with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

This will force the result value to be in decimal format.

```
round(.14*7, digits = 2)
0.98
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting `round`? Why not `print(.14*7, digits = 2)`?

Comment: It´s still nor working. This syntax DF$Value <- round(1.0*0.555, digits = 6) gives me 0.56....

Comment: @SvenJohansson not sure what is going on but running the same code gives me 0.555, as expected.
> x <- round(1.0*0.555, digits = 6)
> x
[1] 0.555
If the issue is part of a larger code chunk (other than just multiplying), can you provide a reproducible example so we can help you figure out the issue? It might also help if you can run sessionInfo() and share the output.

Comment: Many thanks, now I got it.